# Присвоить значение переменной из ресурсов

Tags: java, android, xml

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как присвоить значение переменной (которая из ресурсов) присвоить  из java класса

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется ввиду, что необходимо перезаписать что-то вроде вот такого:

```
getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

То нет, это невозможно. 
Значения из ресурсов не меняются, так как они определены на этапе компиляции.

Comment: вот-вот, фактически их следует рассматривать как константы

Comment: @keekkenen как мне тогда изменить высоту кнопок

Comment: поясните контекст вопроса - где должно производиться изменение ?